# I want to center my images when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, layout, dynamic, resize

I am a graphic designer(freelance) using css to build a page of images it is 3 columns and 5 rows, the page works fine and when you resize the browser it goes down to 2 columns and then 1 column, the only problem is that the columns snap top the left of the browser , when i want them to remain in the center. I have looked at a few methods from here but could not get any to work. I am new to CSS layouts but not HTML. I am trying to do this without bootstrap as i want to learn CSS as i did with HTML.

[here is a link to the page i am trying to build](http://www.kwlstudio.com/test/index_css.html)

Here is the code i am using , i am not sure if it is right...thanks`

```css
     <style type="text/css"> 
           
           body {

           background-color: #F3F3F3;

           font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida    Grande", sans-serif;

           font-size: 18px;

           color: #000;

         }

         #center {

           display: block;

           position: relative;

           top: -12px;

           width: 169px;

           margin: auto;

         }

         #wrapper {

           display: block;

           border: 2px;

           border-color: #FF30;

           margin-left: auto;

           margin-right: auto;

           min-width: 340px;

           max-width: 1040px;

         }

         </style>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
        <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
        <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->

    <html lang="en-US">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1" />
      <title>Kieron Livingstone</title>


    </head>


    <div id="center">
      <img src="img/page/tagname2.gif" width="169" height="28">
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

      <img src="img/ns_o.jpg" name="shaman_nike" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/mos.jpg" name="Image11" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/bo.jpg" name="Image12" width="340" height="200" border="0">

      <img src="img/nw.jpg" name="Image13" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/n_f.jpg" name="Image14" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/s.jpg" name="Image15" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/fr.jpg" name="Image17" width="340" height="200" border="0">



      <img src="img/n_o.jpg" name="Image16" width="340" height="200" border="0">

      <img src="img/h_f.jpg" name="Image18" width="340" height="200" border="0">

      <img src="img/ztm.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/gg.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/1234.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">



      <img src="img/nm.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/bab.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">


      <img src="img/nm.jpg" name="Image19" width="340" height="200" border="0">

    </div>





    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You should add a doctype, close img tags and add a alt attribute to img tags. Moreover, you should indent better. There is a "a" ending tag without an opening one before.

Comment: thanks, i took the alt tags out as they messed up the 'code snippet' and theres a doctype , a was a leftover ...will change that , any ideas about the CSS dynamic question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there's not anything centering the content of your wrapper div at the moment. It just happens to look OK when the viewport's width is >= 1040px because 3 images that are 340px wide fill it up completely, and your margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto take care of centering the wrapper div in the window.

If you add

```
text-align: center;
```

to

```
#wrapper
{
    ...
}
```

then that will take care of centering the things inside your wrapper div.

Comment: No problem. If you're not doing so already, I'd recommend using in-browser tools to see how your page is structured. If you're using Firefox, for example, then either the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension or the in-built Developer Tools are good for inspecting the sizes and styles of your elements, working out what might be causing any issues and also trying out different styles on the fly. (Other popular web browsers and debugging tools are available!)